# Increasing Tomcat server start up time

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I want to increase the server start up timeout in tomcat. Will increasing the connectionTimeout parameter in the Connector tag in server.xml work?

Comment: *Increase* like it's starting too quickly or *improve* like it should start quicker than it currently does?

Comment: The server start is timing out when I deploy a war file. The war file loads some properties takes sometime and hence fails to fully load all the properties.

Comment: Tomcat configuration might be more on topic on serverfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you run Tomcat under Eclipse otherwise you wouldn't have start-up timeout issues.

Go to server view then double click tomcat instance and increase the timeout value in the time out section there which is 45 secs by default.